# create pivot table with aggregates without a join

Tags: sql-server, pivot, aggregate

I think I am trying to do something that cannot be done.  I am trying to create a pivot table, simultaneously doing two pivots by aggregating off two different columns.  I have created a much simplified example to make the point more understandable.

```
CREATE TABLE two_aggregate_pivot (
    ID INT,
    category CHAR(1),
    value INT
)

INSERT INTO dbo.two_aggregate_pivot
    ( ID, category, value )
VALUES  (1, 'A', 100),
        (1, 'B', 97),
        (1, 'D', NULL),
        (2, 'A', 86),
        (2, 'C', 83),
        (2, 'D', 81)
```

I can pivot to get the count of the categories as follows:

```
SELECT  piv1.ID,
        [A] AS cat_A,
        [B] AS cat_B,
        [C] AS cat_C,
        [D] AS cat_D
FROM
(SELECT ID, category FROM dbo.two_aggregate_pivot) SRC
PIVOT
(
    COUNT(category)
    FOR category IN ([A],[B],[C],[D])
) piv1
```

And I get what I want.

```
ID  cat_A   cat_B   cat_C   cat_D
1   1       1       0       1
2   1       0       1       1
```

So too I can write a totally separate query, add the value column in the source select, and aggregate from MAX(value) instead, and get a pivot of max values.

```
ID  val_A   val_B   val_C   val_D
1   100     97      NULL    NULL
2   86      NULL    83      81
```

But what I can't figure out is how to get them both.

```
ID  cat_A   cat_B   cat_C   cat_D    val_A  val_B   val_C   val_D
1   1       1       0       1        100     97      NULL    NULL
2   1       0       1       1        86      NULL    83      81
```

I have seen examples here on stackoverflow using CASE statements to check IS NOT NULL, but that doesn't work for me I don't think, since I can have both missing values and extant values that are really NULL.  I can create two CTEs, one with each PIVOT, then JOIN them.  That gives me the table that I want, but it forces a clustered index scan of the table twice, and then of course the join operator.  The table is quite large, and performance matters, so I want to try to find a way to do both pivots within the same clustered index scan.

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a CROSS APPLY to unpivot your data.   I should add, it would be a small matter to go dynamic.

**Example**

```
Select *
 From  (
            Select ID
                  ,B.*
             From  two_aggregate_pivot A
             Cross Apply (values ('cat_'+category ,1)
                                ,('val_'+category ,value)
                         ) B (Item,Value)
       ) src
  Pivot (sum(value) for item in ([cat_A],[cat_B],[cat_C],[cat_D],[val_A],[val_B],[val_C],[val_D]) ) pvt
```

**Returns**

```
ID  cat_A   cat_B   cat_C   cat_D   val_A   val_B   val_C   val_D
1   1       1       NULL    1       100     97      NULL    NULL
2   1       NULL    1       1       86      NULL    83      81
```

Comment: Sorry for the long delay responding to this.  I have been messing around with this query trying to figure out how the magic works.  Looking at the inner query helps.  I think I can modify this to work in my case, and I will edit this comment to indicate how it performs relative to joining the two pivots.

Comment: @RobertSievers Apologies for the late response.  I was pulled away.  Let me know if I can assist

Comment: Well, here are the results.  The two PIVIOT JOIN method is 30% less efficient than the CROSS APPLY as measured by the execution subtree cost.  Sure enough, the CROSS APPLY has half the logical reads, but it takes twice the CPU time.  Actual duration comes out almost exactly identical.  So if you have a fast disk, use the two pivot join method.  If you have a slow disk and fast CPU, use the CROSS APPLY.

Comment: @RobertSievers Interesting feedback, and something to keep in mind.  However, I tend to work with some kick-ass servers.   Hardware is a great enabler.  :)