# How do I include an additional non-aggregated column for each of my in my PIVOT values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, pivot

I have the following code fragment which gives me the *current results* below.  I'm attempting to add an additional column for each of my pivoted values in order to include the **lastview** data for each of my siteuserid / tagname combo (see *expected results*).  Since this column isn't an aggregation, I don't believe an additional pivot would help.  I've tried multiple ways of adding **lastview**, but it always results in additional rows rather than the desired output.

```sql
create table #taghits (userid int, email varchar(20), tagname varchar(20), hits int, lastview date)

insert into #taghits select 1, 'email1@here.com', 'tag1', 3, '2020-03-24';
insert into #taghits select 2, 'email2@here.com', 'tag1', 1, '2020-03-17';
insert into #taghits select 2, 'email2@here.com', 'tag2', 1, '2020-03-18';
insert into #taghits select 3, 'email3@here.com', 'tag1', 2, '2020-03-25';
insert into #taghits select 3, 'email3@here.com', 'tag2', 5, '2020-03-28';

select * from #taghits;

DECLARE @Columns3 as NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @Columns3 = ISNULL(@Columns3 + ', ','') + QUOTENAME(TagName)
FROM (
    select distinct TagName
    from #taghits
) AS TagNames
ORDER BY TagNames.TagName

DECLARE @scolumns as NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @scolumns = ISNULL(@Scolumns + ', ','')+ 'ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(TagName) + ', 0) AS '+ QUOTENAME(TagName)
FROM (select distinct TagName
    from #taghits) AS TagNames
ORDER BY TagNames.TagName

DECLARE @SQL as NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = '
    select userid, email, ' + @scolumns + '
    from
        (
        select userid, email, tagname, hits
        from #taghits
        ) as TagHits
    PIVOT (
        SUM(hits)
        FOR TagName IN (' + @Columns3 + ')
    ) AS PivotTable
    order by userId
'

exec sp_executesql @SQL;
```

#### Current Result

```
| userid | email           | tag1 | tag2 |
|--------|-----------------|------|------|
| 1      | email1@here.com | 3    | 0    |
| 2      | email2@here.com | 1    | 1    |
| 3      | email3@here.com | 2    | 5    |
```

#### Desired Result

```
| userid | email           | tag1_hits | tag1_lastview | tag2_hits | tag2_lastview |
|--------|-----------------|-----------|---------------|-----------|---------------|
| 1      | email1@here.com | 3         | 2020-03-24    | 0         | null          |
| 2      | email2@here.com | 1         | 2020-03-17    | 1         | 2020-03-18    |
| 3      | email3@here.com | 2         | 2020-03-25    | 5         | 2020-03-28    |
```

Comment: I had a question similar, though not identical, to this.  The answer was to use a CROSS APPLY.  I'd say that I totally understood how the magic worked, but I would be a liar.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46692727/create-pivot-table-with-aggregates-without-a-join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((select distinct ', 
            SUM(CASE WHEN tagname=''' + CAST(tagname as varchar(10)) + ''' THEN [hits] ELSE 0 END) AS [' + CAST(tagname as varchar(10)) + '_hits],
            MAX(CASE WHEN tagname=''' + CAST(tagname as varchar(10)) + ''' THEN [lastview] ELSE NULL END) AS [' + CAST(tagname as varchar(10)) + '_lastview]'
            /*---------------You can add other columns here similar to above--------------*/
            FROM #taghits 
            FOR XML PATH(''),type).value('.','varchar(max)'),1,2,'')
SET @query = 'SELECT userid, email, ' + @Cols + '  FROM #taghits group by userid, email' 

print (@query)
exec(@query)
```

Please see db<>fiddle **[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dd2915e6f0b66880a4cc5f890f1fdca9)**.

Comment: This is great.  It not only answers my question, but shows a much cleaner way of dealing with the actual problem. Avoiding the pivot is much cleaner and I don’t have all the extra code to deal with null values.  The only issue is that it fails if @cols is more than 8000 characters. The statement seems to truncate.

Comment: @Joe-IV glad that helped. you can always create multiple variables to avoid the overflow and execute directly by combining them like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c6bb8135e4c698ab5eb9350ea78d0ea0).